# Find every unique 2 word pairings from a column of terms in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please see: [Extracting and counting unique word frequency from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503637/extracting-and-counting-unique-word-frequency-from-a-range)

In that question the asker was seeking unique single words.
I'm trying to accomplish the same but finding every unique pair of words.
If a cell doesn't have two words, then it doesn't have any entries.
If a cell has 3 words then it would have two combinations A + B and B + C

I've tried to parse with splits and substitute pipes for spaces by using the len(cell) - len(substitute(cell," ","")) which gives me the number of words, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming your words are in Column `A`, put this in cell `B1`):

```
=index(
query(
query(
trim(iferror(flatten(split(
regexreplace(regexreplace(lower(A:A),"[^A-Za-z\ \']+",""),"([\w\']+\ [\w\']+)","$1,")
&","&
regexreplace(regexreplace(lower(if(len(A:A)=len(substitute(A:A," ",""))+1,,A:A)),"[^A-Za-z\ \']+",""),"\w*\ ([\w\']+\ [\w\']+)","$1,")
,",",1,1)),)),
"where Col1 like '% %' order by Col1",1),
"select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1 label Col1 'Word pairs', count(Col1) 'Qty'",0)
)
```

It's quite involved, but I'll break it down if it works for you!