# Finding Unique 2 Word Pairs In Google Sheets And Then Counting The Frequency From A Range ("Phrase Word Cloud")

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

Please see:
[Find every Unique 2 word pairings from a column of terms in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67528281/find-every-unique-2-word-pairings-from-a-column-of-terms-in-google-sheets)

In the above question the asker was was looking for unique 2 word pairings and gave the example of having 3 words in a cell.

The formula given works if there is only 1 to 3 words in a cell, but as soon as you go over (4+ words) the formula returns a #value Error "in ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows"

```
=arrayformula(query(flatten({query({if(A:A<>"",iferror(trim(split(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(lower(A:A),"[^A-Za-z\ \']+",""),"([\w\']+\ [\w\']+)","$1,"),"(.*\,)(.*)","$1"),",")),),)},"where Col1 is not null",0);query({if(A:A<>"",iferror(trim(split(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(lower(if(len(A:A)=len(regexreplace(A:A," ",""))+1,,A:A)),"[^A-Za-z\ \']+",""),"(\w*)(\ )([\w\']+\ [\w\']+)","$3,"),"(.*\,)(.*)","$1"),",")),),)},"where Col1 is not null",0)}),"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Word pairs',Count(Col1) 'Qty' ",0))
```

Is it possible to make the formula work with cells that include 25, 50, 100+ words and then be able to exclude common words from a column like done in [Extracting and counting unique word frequency from a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503637/extracting-and-counting-unique-word-frequency-from-a-range)

```
   =ArrayFormula(query(transpose(split(query(regexreplace(A1:A5, "[^A-Za-z\s/']" ,""),,50000)," ")), "Select Col1, Count(Col1) where not UPPER(Col1) matches '\b"&textjoin("|", 1, UPPER(J1:J20))&"\b'  group by Col1 order by Count(Col1) desc label Count(Col1)''"))
```

I'm trying to find unique word pairings in sentences and then count how many times they appear.

I've edited my question to try to make it more readable
(sorry still don't completely now how to use stack-overflow formatting or respond to comments etc.)

TEXT column and EXCLUSIONS is the input

UNIQUE PAIRS and COUNT would be the Output

| TEXT | UNIQUE PAIRS | COUNT | EXCLUSIONS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I wake up with night sweats and struggle with staying asleep. | night sweats | 2 | I wake |
| I wake up from night sweats and struggle with dry hair. | staying asleep | 1 | wake up |
|  | dry hair | 1 | up with |
|  |  |  | with night |
|  |  |  | sweats and |
|  |  |  | and struggle |
|  |  |  | with staying |
|  |  |  | struggle with |
|  |  |  | up from |
|  |  |  | from night |
|  |  |  | with dry |

Purpose is to be able to find common word pairings like

bed head, dry hair, night sweats, etc.

That you can't find just by looking at the frequency of single words

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: `the formula breaks`. Define breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, LAMBDA(x, QUERY(QUERY(x&" "&{QUERY(x, 
 "offset 1", ); ""}, "where not Col1 contains '×××'", ), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''"))
 (FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN({REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(a), "[\.,\?!\(\)]", ), 
 IFERROR(a/0, "×××")}),,9^9), " "))))(A1:A2))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, LAMBDA(x, QUERY(QUERY(x&" "&{QUERY(x, 
 "offset 1", ); ""}, "where not Col1 contains '×××'", ), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, UNIQUE(LOWER(E2:E)))&"' 
  group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''"))
 (FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN({REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(a), "[\.,\?!\(\)]", ), 
 IFERROR(a/0, "×××")}),,9^9), " "))))(A1:A2))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to add an exclusion column to this formula? As besides that it seems to work great

Comment: @bham answer updated